# my footer expands until top of the container before that

Tags: html, css

[image]

[image]

The footer that I want it to be in the bottom extends to the top of the blocks that are not related to it. I tried to edit both block and main-footer properties height also made the footers position sticky still not worked.
Thanks

Comment: Hello please post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help.  Also [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875598/edit) your question to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

use `position: fixed;` and  `bottom:0px;` in your #main-footer css

Comment: But I want it to be fixed in the bottom

Comment: I didn't get it exactly but according to the sources The explanation is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Remove Display: block; form footer it will help you in this